# problem installing Xprivacy : where is the install button?

Tags: xprivacy

I try to install Xprivacy but I cannot find the install button.
When I click on the app logo on my phone, I get the below screen.

Clicking on check for root, gets me the new message "Device is rooted"
even if I am quite sure it is not.
Probably the missing check mark means that it is not rooted (a bit confusing).

I assume that I first need to root the phone

Correct ?

[image]

Comment: Are you using an Android version older than Nougat (Android 7)? XPrivacy officially only supports Android up to Lollipop (Android 5) and works up to Android 6. Above that, it doesn't work anymore. So you better use its successor, XPrivacyLUA. You still need to root your device and install the Xposed framework, though.

Comment: @Izzy. I am using Android 6.  Thank you for letting me know the existence of XPrivacyLUA.   I'll give it a try.

Comment: Also, other than XPrivacy, XPrivacyLUA is still supported and actively maintained.

Comment: Why are you using some sort of "XPrivacy Installer", anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your device need to be rooted for Xprivacy to work, be installed properly. Even before installing it, you must install Xposed framework which requires root.

From [Xprivacy Github page](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacy):

> XPrivacy is built using the Xposed framework, which it uses to tap into a vast number of carefully selected Android functions.

> Root access is needed to install the Xposed framework.

The process is:

1. Root your device.
2. Install Xposed installer.
3. Install Xposed framework.
4. Install Xprivacy.

Comment: Tank you for your answer.   I suppose / hope I will get a different screen once my device is rooted.   I'll post it once I tried it out.